# My code in Pascal does not want to work correctly. What is the problem in?

Tags: recursion, sum, pascal

I am writing program: sum of real numbers using recursive function.
What is wrong with it? It shows me just last entered numebr.

```
type
 Indexy = 1..100;
 TPoleReal = array [Indexy] of Real;

var
 j: word;
 r, realRes: real;
 tpr: TPoleReal;


function SoucetCisel(n: TPoleReal; j: word): real;
 begin
   if j>0 then begin
     SoucetCisel:=SoucetCisel + n[j];
     j:=j-1;
   end
 end;


begin i:=0; j:=0;
while not seekeof do begin
  read(r); Inc(j);
  tpr[j]:=r;
  writeln(j, ' ', tpr[j]);
end;
realRes:= SoucetCisel(tpr, j);
writeln(realRes);

end.
```

Comment: What development environment are you using, FPC + Lazarus or what?

Comment: Hey, you're not passing params in the recursion. Change SoucetCisel:=SoucetCisel + n[j]; by SoucetCisel:=SoucetCisel(n, j-1) + n[j]; thus you can drop j:=j-1; because you're not using that line. I also suggest to pass the array by reference to make the recursion more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I told you in a comment before. Try this code for your pascal program:

```
type
 Indexy = 1..100;
 TPoleReal = array [Indexy] of Real;

var
 j: word;
 r, realRes: real;
 tpr: TPoleReal;


function SoucetCisel(n: TPoleReal; j: word): real;
 begin
   if j>0 then begin
     SoucetCisel:=SoucetCisel(n, j-1) + n[j];
   end
 end;


begin i:=0; j:=0;
while not seekeof do begin
  read(r); Inc(j);
  tpr[j]:=r;
  writeln(j, ' ', tpr[j]);
end;
realRes:= SoucetCisel(tpr, j);
writeln(realRes);

end.
```

Answer (score 2):

For debugging purposes I suggest you simplify the main part of your code to

```
begin
  i:=0;
  j:=0;
  tpr[j] := 1;
  Inc(j);
  tpr[2] := 2;
  realRes:= SoucetCisel(tpr, j);
  writeln(realRes);
end.
```

That should make it make it much easier to appreciate what the problem is.

The first problem with your SoucetCisel function is that it isn't actually recursive.

A recursive function is one which calls itself with altered arguments, as in the
archetypical Factorial function

```
function Factorial(N : Integer)
begin
  if N = 1 then
    Factorial := 1
  else
    Factorial := N * Factorial(N - 1);
end;
```

The recursive call in this is the line

```
Factorial := Factorial(N - 1);
```

Your SoucetCisel doesn't do that, it simply adds the initial value of the function result
to the value of `n[j]`, so it is not recursive at all.

The other problem is that, as written, it has no defined return value.  In all the
Pascal implementations I've come across, the return value is undefined on entry to the
function and stays undefined until some value is explicitly assigned to it.  The
function result is usually some space on the stack which the compiler-generated
code of the function reserves but which initially (on entry to the function) holds some random value, resulting from previous usage of the stack.

So, what the result of your SoucetCisel function is evaluated from is effectively

```
SoucetCisel := ARandomNumber + n[j]
```

which of course is just another random number.  Obviously, you fix this aspect
of your function by ensuring that an explicit assignment to the function result is made
immediately on entry to the function.  As a general rule,  **all** execution paths through a function should lead through a statement which explicitly assigns a
value to the function result.

Then, you need to rewrite the remainder of it so that it actually is recursive
in the way your task requires.

While you're doing those two things, I would suggest that you use a more
helpful parameter name than the anonymous 'n'.  'n' is usually used to refer to an uninteresting integer.

**update** I'm not sure from your comment whether it was supposed to be serious.  In case it was, consider these two functions

```
function SumOfReals(Reals : TPoleReal; j : word): real;
var
   i : Integer;
begin
  SumOfReals := 0;
  for i := 1 to j do
    SumOfReals := SumOfReals + Reals[i];
end;

function SumOfRealsRecursive(Reals : TPoleReal; j : word): real;
var
  i : Integer;
begin
 SumOfRealsRecursive := Reals[j];
 if j > 1 then
   SumOfRealsRecursive := SumOfRealsRecursive + SumOfRealsRecursive(Reals, j -1);
end;
```

These functions both do the same thing, namely evaluate the sum of the contents
of the Reals array up to and including the index `j`.   The first one does so iteratively,
simply traversing the Reals array, which the second does it recursively.  However,
it should be obvious that the recursive version is absolutely pointless *in this case* because
the iterative version does the same thing but far more efficiently, because
it does not involve copying the entire Reals array for each recursive call, which the recursive version does.

Comment: mt program is about sum of numbers that are entered, not factorial :)

Comment: I know that, thank you.  I just mentioned Factorial because it is the example recursive function most people have come across.  At least I hope it is clear by comparison with it, your SoucetCisel is not recursive, which is one of the reasons it does not do what you were expecting it to.  That was your question, wasn't it?